# Record type error in SOQL

Tags: apex, record-type

I am trying to display contact records depending upon record type.But when I am trying to retrieve it is showing error as  `Compile Error: No such column 'RecordType' on entity 'Contact'`

Here is my SOQL `for(Contact c: [SELECT Id, Name  FROM Contact where RecordType = 'X'limit 10])`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The field is RecordTypeID. If you are comparing by record type name then use, 'RecordType.Name'.

Comment: RecordType.DeveloperName is better as it can't be changed, the Name can be.

Answer (score -1):

It worked :

```
for(Contact c: [SELECT Id, Name  FROM Contact where RecordType.Name = 'X'limit 10]
```

Thank you Rajan:)